# Don't say someone who rejected an edit approved it

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

On [this page](https://askubuntu.com/tools/suggested-edits?filter=all&tab=Controversial), it says "approved by Community, David Foerster 20 hours ago".

[image]

When you follow the link, it takes you to [the review page](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/724066), but David Foerster actually rejected it:

[image]

Please don't say it was approved by them when they rejected it.

Comment: Community approval means that the OP (who hasn't enough rep points) accepted the edit suggestion to their post, right?

Comment: @ByteCommander Correct.

Comment: I guess the simplest solution would be to replace "approved" with "reviewed".

Comment: @terdon That would be pretty sensible, rather than changing the backend.